# Is it possible to get the number of commits in last pull ?

Tags: git, git-commit

Assume that i am pulling changes from the repo to update my local repository. The changes which I pulled includes 4 commits. Is there any way to get the number of commits in the recent "git pull" ? Thanks!

Comment: After pulling or before?

Comment: @JohnZwinck After Pulling.

Answer (score 6):

Git stores previous states for references, you can query them with `<refname>@{<n>}` syntax. Pull operation performs merging thus updating `HEAD` and branch references. You can find state of `HEAD` prior to update with `HEAD@{1}` (or `branch_name@{1}` for branch reference) and then find range of pulled commits with `HEAD@{1}..HEAD`. Then you can do with this commits whatever you want:

- count them: `git rev-list HEAD@{1}..HEAD@{0} --count`
- list log: `git log HEAD@{1}..HEAD@{0}`

Specific reference `ORIG_HEAD` can be used instead of `HEAD@{1}`, but `<refname>@{<n>}` is more general and more powerful tool to study.

Comment: This answer is correct (and upvoted) but I think it's worth mentioning that `git pull` actually runs *two* Git commands, which are `git fetch` followed by whichever second command you choose—the default is `git merge`, but you can choose `git rebase`. It's the *second* command, whether merge or rebase, that updates `HEAD` and thus sets `ORIG_HEAD` and creates a reflog entry. You'll find `ORIG_HEAD` mentioned in both the `git merge` and the `git rebase` documentation. There are some rare corner cases for `git pull` where it doesn't run the second command; in this case, there's no update.